# SQL: Populating missing months and values

Tags: sql, missing-data

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
Accountno | MonthPeriod | YearPeriod | Value | StartYear | StartMonth | EndYear | Endmonth
---------- ------------- ------------ ------- ----------- ------------ ---------  --------
210         4               2015         100      2015            1      2016       5
210         2               2016         200      2015            1      2016       5
300         4               2015         50       2015            1      2016       5
300         2               2016         100      2015            1      2016       5
```

I am looking for a way to fill in the missing months and years between the startmonth/startyear and endmonth/endyear, where the values for the newly populated entries will be of the previously populated values - populating the values backwards if that makes any sense? And for the entries towards the endyear/endmonth the accountno's last value (As the desired output table below)

```
Accountno | MonthPeriod | YearPeriod | Value | StartYear | StartMonth | EndYear | Endmonth
---------- ------------- ------------ ------- ----------- ------------ ---------  --------
210         1               2015         100      2015            1      2016       5
210         2               2015         100      2015            1      2016       5
210         3               2015         100      2015            1      2016       5
210         4               2015         200      2015            1      2016       5
210         5               2015         200      2015            1      2016       5
210         6               2015         200      2015            1      2016       5
210         7               2015         200      2015            1      2016       5
210         8               2015         200      2015            1      2016       5
210         9               2015         200      2015            1      2016       5
210         10              2015         200      2015            1      2016       5
210         11              2015         200      2015            1      2016       5
210         12              2015         200      2015            1      2016       5
210         1               2016         200      2015            1      2016       5
210         2               2016         200      2015            1      2016       5
210         3               2016         200      2015            1      2016       5
210         4               2016         200      2015            1      2016       5
210         5               2016         200      2015            1      2016       5
300         1               2015         50       2015            1      2016       5
300         2               2015         50       2015            1      2016       5
300         3               2015         50       2015            1      2016       5
300         4               2015         50       2015            1      2016       5
300         5               2015         100      2015            1      2016       5
300         6               2015         100      2015            1      2016       5
300         7               2015         100      2015            1      2016       5
300         8               2015         100      2015            1      2016       5
300         9               2015         100      2015            1      2016       5
300        10               2015         100      2015            1      2016       5
300        11               2015         100      2015            1      2016       5
300        12               2015         100      2015            1      2016       5
300         1               2016         100      2015            1      2016       5
300         2               2016         100      2015            1      2016       5
300         3               2016         100      2015            1      2016       5
300         4               2016         100      2015            1      2016       5
300         5               2016         100      2015            1      2016       5
```

I tried manipulating the following code for my situation but did not exceed:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST( Month tinyint, Year int, Value int)

INSERT INTO TEST(Month, Year, Value)
VALUES
(1,2013,100),
(4,2013,101),
(8,2013,102),
(2,2014,103),
(4,2014,104)

DECLARE @Months Table(Month tinyint)
Insert into @Months(Month)Values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),    (11),(12);


With tblValues as (
select Rank() Over (ORDER BY y.Year, m.Month) as [Rank], 
      m.Month, 
      y.Year, 
      t.Value
from @Months m
CROSS JOIN ( Select Distinct Year from Test ) y
LEFT JOIN Test t on t.Month = m.Month and t.Year = y.Year
)
Select t.Month, t.Year, COALESCE(t.Value, t1.Value) as Value
from tblValues t
left join tblValues t1 on t1.Rank = (
        Select Max(tmax.Rank)
        From tblValues tmax 
        Where tmax.Rank < t.Rank AND tmax.Value is not null)

Order by t.Year, t.Month
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The rules are a bit opaque at this stage, which makes it difficult to help. Could you explain the meaning of MonthPeriod and YearPeriod? Also, what happens if endMonth and endYear are different for different rows of the same accountNo?

Comment: @wwkudu Monthperiod and Yearperiod is the observation month and year for which there is an entry(for the example above, Accountno 210 had an observation for month 4(April) in 2015 and again in month 2 (Feb) 2016 - I suppose calling it ObservationMonth and ObservationYear would make more sense?). The endMonth and endYear will always be the same for all rows for all of the AccountNo's (endMonth and endYear is a 'fixed' value that I will input as I want to calculate all the missing months between StartMonth/StartYear and EndMonth/EndYear). Does that make more sense?